# How to process uploaded file and for data in same servlet?

Tags: java, forms, servlets, file-upload

I am uploading files using servlets. Now, i want to process some user input/form data in the same servlet. Is that possible? If, its possible means, how?

As far what i know is, doPost() method have an `if` condition to check whether the request contains mutilpart data and in `else` block the form processing. How the both `if` & `else` block getting execute? I am confused.

Any suggestions!!!

Comment: You won't be able to execute *both* the `if` and `else` blocks in the same request.  But it sounds like you don't need to - *if* it's a multipart post, handle it as an upload, *else* hand it as a form submission.

Comment: `doPost` has any statements you put there. What is confusing you? if multipart, process file, process data anyway, **not in else**. A code snippet may be helpful here.

Comment: @khachik : i am already uploading files using a servlet. Now i want to process some form data using that same servlet, while uploading file. Is it possible!!

Comment: @ Andrzej Doyle: I want to do the both in same servlet at same time. Is that possible!

Comment: @CS 1.6 Yes that is pretty possible

Comment: @org.life.java: How? Can you explain me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `if-else` blocks are in a `for` or `while` loop over `List<FileItem>`, right? The loop just keeps repeating the piece of `if-else` code until there are no items anymore.

I must however admit that the `FileItem` is a misleading name. `MultipartItem` has been a better name.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)
- [`for` statement tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)
- [`while` statement tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Servlet 3.0, you'll be pleased to know that it comes with **Asynchronous Processing**. With asynchronous processing, a thread is called to handle a resource and return back to the container without being blocked.

There is a good explanation on [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html) which explains Asynchrous Processing. I don't know if that's what you're looking for.